# Is there any standard separating java 8 and higher versions from java versions under 8?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm searching for the reason why my IntelliJ download tool doesn't show Java versions under 1.8.
[image]

I searched about Java version history, but all I found is that Java 8 is still widely used and the reason why. I could not find any information about versions under 8.

Is there any standard separating java 8 and higher versions from java versions under 8? If so, why?

Comment: Not what I know of. Maybe they just thought that no one uses 10 years old Java versions in practice anyway (which ought to be true).

Comment: AFAIK the primary difference is that Oracle no longer provides any (not even paid!) support for Java before 8. The only commercially supported Java 7 release is by Azul (a third party). Also, I'm reasonably sure that this only removed the ability to automagically download a JDK for you, but doesn't stop you from installing one manually and using that (though I would **strongly** discourage using a JDK that old and unsupported)

Comment: Java 7 and lower are [no longer supported](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history) (though Azul supports Java 7 until 2027), so likely JetBrains used that as a reason not to offer downloads for Java 7 and lower (i.e. only supply *supported* versions (though then it is odd they offer downloads for 13, 15, 16 and 18 which are no longer supported). However, this seems to be asking for opinions, which is off-topic.